# How to remove character with specific pattern form data frame in R

Tags: r

Im trying to remove the all the characters starting with the pattern "Gm" from last column of my data.frame

My data.frame looks like this

```
level   logp  chr   start    end     CNA      Genes                                                           
  3     1.4   3      100     110    gain     Gm5852,Gm5773,Tdpoz4,Tdpoz3,Gm911                      
  4     18.10 3      962      966   gain     Fcgr1,Terc,Gm5703
```

The result should look something like this

```
level   logp     chr   start    end     CNA           Genes                                                           
   3     1.4      3      100     110    gain    Tdpoz4,Tdpoz3                   
   4     18.10    3      962     966    gain    Fcgr1,Terc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a data frame `d`:

```
d$Genes_new <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(d$Genes),split=','),function(s) paste(s[!grepl('^Gm',s)],collapse=','))

#  level logp chr start end  CNA                             Genes     Genes_new
#1     3  1.4   3   100 110 gain Gm5852,Gm5773,Tdpoz4,Tdpoz3,Gm911 Tdpoz4,Tdpoz3
#2     4 18.1   3   962 966 gain                 Fcgr1,Terc,Gm5703    Fcgr1,Terc
```

Here, `strsplit(as.character(d$Genes),split=',')` creates a list of comma-separated gene names for each row, and `sapply` applies to each element of this list a function that excludes all gene names starting from Gm (`s[!grepl('^Gm',s)]`) and concatenates the remaining genes (`paste(.,collapse=',')`.

Answer (score 5):

This uses a single `gsub` to remove the unwanted portions:

```
Genes <- c("Gm5852,Gm5773,Tdpoz4,Tdpoz3,Gm911", "Fcgr1,Terc,Gm5703") # test data
gsub(",?Gm[^,]*,?", "", Genes)
```

giving:

```
[1] "Tdpoz4,Tdpoz3" "Fcgr1,Terc"
```

Here is a visualization of the regular expression:

```
,?Gm[^,]*,?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/KHugBTRjFCd4F46c)